# Почему гладкий микрометр называют "гладким"?

Tags: этимология, терминология

[Гладкий микрометр](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) - что означает прилагательное "гладкий"? Гладкость хода или же то, что прибор предназначен для измерения гладких поверхностей? Задумался о переводе термина на английский, имеющиеся в интернете ответы (smooth-action micrometer; Engineer's hand micrometer) не устраивают.

Надеюсь, техническая терминология не является оффтопиком. На английском форуме с готовностью отвечают на подобные вопросы, да к счастью есть и Engineering StackExchange.

Comment: *На английском форуме с готовностью отвечают на подобные вопросы* - оно-то так, но учтите, что мнение местных обитателей (в основном - филологов-любителей) не всегда компетентно в вопросах технической терминологии. Как надо слово, даже термин, произносить и писать - это всегда пожалуйста, а вот вопросы, непосредственно завязанные на дела чисто инженерные, могут оказаться не под силу.

Comment: @behemothus - да, я попытаюсь учесть. Зарегистрировался на тематическом форуме по металлообработке. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что он построен на принципе "микрометрической пары": гайки и микрометрического винта, рабочей частью которого является "гладкая" (нерезьбованная) часть.